# What would cause Random Forest to not predict the values on the tails?

Tags: r, random-forest, continuous-data, variable

In the scatterplot below you can seen that my Random Forest prediction does not predict values at the extremes(i.e above 200) on my test data.  My training data has values in that range, just not that many as compared to the mid to low range values (i.e., 50-150). Can anyone provide a quick answer of why this may happen?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

RF regression predictions are the average of the contents of the terminal nodes. Observations in the tails are, by definition, not near the average.

Comment: Axiom.  Nicely done.